# Quarto extension installed but not found during render

Tags: r, rstudio, pandoc, quarto

Environment: RStudio 2022.12.0+353, Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

I am writing a scientific manuscript using Quarto/RStudio. I just installed the [section-bibliographies filter](https://github.com/pandoc-ext/section-bibliographies) as an extension using `quarto install extension pandoc-ext/section-bibliographies` which concluded with "Extension installation complete". I now see the _extensions subdirectory in the project directory. I also updated the YAML as described in the section-bibliographies/README:

```
---
filters: 
  - section-bibliographies
bibliography: refs.bib
reference-section-title: References
citeproc: false
---
```

However, when I render the .qmd file, it errors with "Error running filter section-bibliographies: Could not find executable section-bibliographies". Before adding the section-bibliographies filter, the document rendered without any errors. In troubleshooting this, I installed the latest version of Quarto, but that did not fix the issue. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: This filter is working fine in my case (using quarto version `1.2.335`)

Comment: I am also using quarto version `1.2.335`.

Comment: Did you check whether `section-bibliographies.lua` file exists inside the `_extensions/section-bibliographies` directory?

Comment: You could try to specify the full filter path: `_extensions/pandoc-ext/section-bibliographies/section-bibliographies.lua`.

Comment: @shafee The lua file is here: `_extensions/pandoc-ext/section-bibliographies/section-bibliographies.lua`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion made by @tarleb, I added the full filter path (from the project directory) to the YAML. During rendering, that produced the following error:

> "Error running filter _extensions/pandoc-ext/section-bibliographies/section-bibliographies.lua:
> cannot open _extensions/pandoc-ext/section-bibliographies/section-bibliographies.lua: No such file or directory".

I then provided the full filter path (i.e., from my computer's top-level directory) and that allowed rendering without errors. However, I also had to remove `citeproc: false` from the YAML for the citations to be formatted and for the references to be displayed at the end of each H1 section. The only remaining glitch is that, in addition to references at the end of each H1 section, there is another section at the end of the rendered document containing all references. Finally, for completeness, in the Background Jobs window the rendering step also produces warnings for each figure, for example:

> "[WARNING] Citeproc: citation fig-lineplot not found".

Despite this, the figures and figure citations are formatted as expected.

Comment: Thank you, this worked in my case. But @tarleb: What's the reason? Why is it not working as stated in the [README](https://github.com/pandoc-ext/section-bibliographies#quarto) and would it be worth giving a hint there?

Comment: @winnewoerp feel free to raise a PR to add this info to the README. I don't know what's going on there, looks like a Quarto issue.

Comment: It is worth stating that although the fix I provided allows the section-bibliographies filter to work, the absolute file path will cause the code to break whenever the file structure changes, including when the code is used on different computers.

Comment: Thanks @mtnrambler for pointing out this downside of the solution. Retrieving the path to the current .qmd file programmatically would help, but I have no idea if and how this can be done.